# can't use PowerShellGet module under Powershell 7

Tags: powershell, powershell-module, package-management, powershellget

Just installed latest Powershell7, but found that can't use PowerShellGet module command anymore, giving me below error,
[image]

thanks for any info.

I should still use commands like find-module and install-module under powershell 7;
I already know I can use find-psresource, install-psresource instead;
Just try to figure out what happened under the hood;